# Evaluate whole django queryset in one database hit

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to evaluate a whole django queryset in **one** database hit.
I'm using Django 2.0.8 with Python 3.6.5. 
 I used to evaluate querysets listing them:

```
queryset = Model.objects.all()
# len(connection.queries) = 0
list(queryset)
# len(connection.queries) = 87
len(queryset) = 43
```

which only performed one database hit. But now, it looks like this is hitting the database more than *n* times -*n* being the length of the queryset- which is a problem when *n* is large and the database hits costly. 

 
Thanks

Comment: This is already performed with *one* hit.

Comment: Did you by any chance "consume" related objects?

Comment: It was the case when I did it with previous django versions, but now it doesn't look like it does. See my edit

Comment: can you look at the `connection.queries`? For example share the last 5, and take a look if those are not fetches of *related* objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean by "consuming" related objects?

Comment: @CharlesSioti: if you have `some_object.my_foreignkey`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: You assumption is *wrong*. If you evaluate the queryset, you will immediately fetch *all* the results in one query.

So for the `list(..)`, where you enumerate over the queryset, Django will first make a query, fetch all records with that query, and then *deserialize* all rows, and put it in a list.

There is however linear behavior, since the size of the answer will scale with the number of records, and the amount of work to deserialize it, and put it in a list will also scale with the number of rows.

If your query has `prefetch_related` calls, this will also result in some extra queries, but these (the *number* of queries) will typically scale *linear* with the number of *prefeches*, not in the number of records.

If you plan to fetch a lot of foreign keys, for example:

```
for obj in Model.objects.all():
    print(obj.some_reversefk.all())
```

Then this will make a query *per* object to fetch the *related* object (the object to which the foreign key points).

To avoid that, you can use `.select_related(..)` and `.prefetch_related(..)`. The `.prefetch_related(..)` will make one or two extra queries, but will fetch *all* related objects, at once. So you can use:

```
Model.objects.prefetch_related('some_m2m')
```

Comment: You're right. Only one query is for the original model, the rest are for *related objects*. So should I perform a *select_related* or *prefetch_related* prior to this ?

Comment: @CharlesSiouti: if is a many-to-one (`ForeignKey`), or one-to-one (`OneToOneField`), you can use `select_related`, for everything that can act as a *multiplier* however, you should use `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a single hit in database.read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/

Even if your model has related fields , it would fetch your non-related fields in single query. For accessing all related fields data as well, first read about classic  N+1 query problem, read https://medium.com/@hakibenita/things-you-must-know-about-django-admin-as-your-app-gets-bigger-6be0b0ee9614

Btw, if your model has too many objects, avoid using `.all()` in `list()`, it will load all the objects in memory. Instead use `.count()`